# Raid controller emitting warnings ... what's next?

Tags: hard-drive, troubleshooting, raid

Sometimes when I boot, the RAID bios is telling me "Error occured".

My computer is a Intel based, with ICH9R southbridge (intel Q6600 processor).

The raid controller is the integrated one, and I plugged two Samsung 1 TB hdd.

I set up a raid matrix, having 300 MB on a RAID 1 array and the remaining on a RAID 0 array.

I can boot the computer with no other sign, everything is working (both raid arrays are working).

When I ran the Intel Rapid Storage utility, it tells me the RAID 1 array is "degraded" and that one of the HDD has fault.

I can set it back to normal, the RAID 1 is rebuild...

All of this is scarying me, I rebackuped everything I need, but I want to know what's happening, and what I have to do to prevent a real HDD crash.

Is there anything I can do to isolate the problem, in order to take preventive action ?

Comment: I have made some crasy matrix arrays before, but the one I would prefer not to make is to mix up mirroring 1 with striping 0, on the same 2 disks.  mentally when I attempt to figure out how it is going to work, I really have neither speed nor redundancy :-) I have to break one to fix the other, how can that be redundant?  I am just saying . . . .

Comment: Other approach requires either more disks or sacrifying more space. None of this was possible for me. Why do you think that there is no redundancy ?

Comment: In raid0 removing one disk renders the raid0 data useless and unrecoverable (split). In raid1 replacing one disk is how you fix a hardware issue (disk fail).   . . plus having a mirror of a hosed or virused system doesnt do a lot of good anyway.  . it is just my opinion that it would be better off with an manually made image or clone backup of 100% operational system for standard users anyway. (vrses servers)

Answer (score 1):

Replace the failing drive. Rebuild the array. Do not touch the drive you removed until you confirm the array has rebuilt successfully. Then you can test the drive extensively using whatever tools you want. If it passes those tests, you can re-use it. If it fails them, return it if it's under warranty or discard it if it's not.

But priority one should be to protect your data. Replace the drive immediately and rebuild the array. Then worry about whether the drive is okay.

Answer (score 0):

Check SMART status of both hard disks. Did your controller give you any additional information about what was wrong? Defective sectors, ...?

Comment: How can I access smart info ? Speccy see two physical hard drives not for the physical HDD, but for each RAID array

Comment: Never had such a controller running, but [Intel says](http://www.intel.com/support/chipsets/imsm/sb/CS-015002.htm) the controller software should be able to print it.

Comment: Ok, I found a message in the Intel tool : `Blocs with media fault : 24` (not of the actual english message, I translated it from French `Blocs avec erreurs de support : 24`). This message appears on the state page of the RAID 1 array.

Comment: Is there any ID next to this message? Maybe also a hex code. This could be the number of defective sectors, if so, make sure you backup important data on your raid0 (you did anyway, didn't you?) because defective sectors are a very good sign for dying hard disks and often multiply very fast. Maybe you find the best-matching message on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) yourself?

Comment: unfortunately, there is no error code. The tool is a end-user. Maybe I should try to find a more power-user oriented tool